# Javascript SPA Multilanguage and LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, breeze, single-page-application, durandal

I am developing a JavaScript SPA using DurandalJs and BreezeJs as main technologies in the client side. I would like to know what libraries I can use to do my application support different languages. I have been doing a little of searching and I have found that JED.js (http://slexaxton.github.com/Jed/) can be a good option for this task.

However I am not very sure, can somebody recommend nay library for this task, or give me some opinion about JED.js.

Also I would like to ask about some library for store information in the browser. Can somebody recommend me one? I have thought in amplify.js, it gives good functionality for doing request to the server and caching this information. But in my application I am using breezejs, so this part is not needed. I only need to store some data like the username and some little information.

Very thanks.

MY SOLUTION:

I have implemented my system using amplify.storage for storing information in the browser and i18next (http://i18next.com/) to make my application avaliable in different human-languages.

Answer (score 2):

I am not much help on the first part of your question. I'm quite interested in the response myself!

I do have some thoughts on local storage. AmplifyJS is really three independent libraries. One of them, [**amplify.store**](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/), is dedicated to the local storage issue and is worth looking at. You might look at [**lawnchair**](http://brian.io/lawnchair/). Finally, look at the [**Breeze DocCode sample**](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/doccode) for examples of storing full and partial entity caches in browser local storage; it's primitive but gives you hints.

Comment: Thank @Ward, using amplifyJs for store is definitively the best option for me. Also, If I decide to do my application works in offline mode, I will use a mix of breeze(http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/exportimport) and amplifyJs.